# Preset current date and time in input type "datetime" using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, datetime

How can I preset the value in datetime input to current date and time using php or javascript?

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="followupon">
```

What I have..
[image]

What I want...
[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well.. You can just set the value by using the "value" attribute:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="followupon" value="2014-01-02T11:42:13.510">
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Value for more information

If you want to use the current date, you can use php like so:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="followupon" value=<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); ?>">
```